# framer motion svg pathLength 1 being more than full

Tags: reactjs, svg, jsx, framer-motion

i want to make this animation where it looks like it draws an svg image and it works but only with some svgs, i makes the pathLength go from 0 to 1 but it seems like some svg paths even if the pathLength is 0.5 it is still the full image

```
const handleSvg = async () => {
        const svgDrawDuration = 3;
        const svgFadeInOutDuration = 0.5;
        const timeUntilVisible = 1.5;
        const repeatDelay = 1;

        startSvg("#path", { strokeOpacity: 1 }, { duration: svgFadeInOutDuration, delay: timeUntilVisible });
        startSvg("#path", { fillOpacity: 1 }, { duration: svgFadeInOutDuration, delay: ( svgDrawDuration - svgFadeInOutDuration ) + timeUntilVisible });
        await startSvg("#path", { pathLength: 1 }, { duration: svgDrawDuration, ease: 'easeInOut', delay: timeUntilVisible });

        startSvg("#path", { strokeOpacity: 0 }, { duration: svgFadeInOutDuration, delay: ( svgDrawDuration - svgFadeInOutDuration ) + repeatDelay });
        startSvg("#path", { fillOpacity: 0 }, { duration: svgFadeInOutDuration, delay: svgFadeInOutDuration + repeatDelay });
        await startSvg("#path", { pathLength: 0 }, { duration: svgDrawDuration, ease: "easeInOut", delay: repeatDelay });
        
        setTimeout(() => handleSvg(), 500);
    }

<svg ref={scope}
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                        <motion.path id="path"
                        className={styles.svgAnimation}

                        initial={{
                            strokeOpacity: 0,
                            fillOpacity: 0,
                            pathLength: 0,
                        }}

                        strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round"
                        d="M10.5 6h9.75M10.5 6a1.5 1.5 0 1 1-3 0m3 0a1.5 1.5 0 1 0-3 0M3.75 6H7.5m3 12h9.75m-9.75 0a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-3 0m3 0a1.5 1.5 0 0 0-3 0m-3.75 0H7.5m9-6h3.75m-3.75 0a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-3 0m3 0a1.5 1.5 0 0 0-3 0m-9.75 0h9.75" />
                    </svg>
```

with this specific svg path i want pathLength 1 to mean it is full and any less meaning its not full, but this one i think the full path is something like 0.5

Comment: That's because your path is a compound path - containing multiple subpaths. The [`pathLength` ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pathLength) calculation becomes quite tricky as it takes the longest segments real path length as a reference. The calculation for the full dash length is like this:  `pathLengthRange / (totalLength/longest)` in your case `1/ (68.77835/9.75)`. So the value for a complete stroke would be  ~ 0.142. Unfortunately, compound paths slightly undermine the benefit of the `pathlength` attribute (using relative dash lengths)

Comment: @herrstrietzel is there any way to easily fix it or is it quite complex